# javascript multidimensional Typed array (Int8Array) example

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, typed-arrays, typedarray

I tried to use Typed arrays instead of arrays, to reduce memory:

```js
function createarrayInt8(numrows,numcols,number){
       
 var arr = new Int8Array(numrows);
         
 for (var i = 0; i < numrows; ++i){
  var columns = new Int8Array(numcols);
  for (var j = 0; j < numcols; ++j){
   columns[j] = number;
  }
  arr[i] = columns;
 }
  
 return arr; 
}
```

But i can't create multidimensional Typed array. 
Why?
Do i have to cast only the "number" var to Int8?

Comment: Well, a typed array can only store values of its type. A uint8 array can therefore only store unsigned 8 bit integers, but not arrays (of uints).

Comment: i almost thought so :). But how can it get a multidimensional array that stores only unsigned 8 bit integers to reduce the used memory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A typed `Int8Array` can only hold 8-bit integers. So `arr[i] = columns` won't work since columns is of type `Int8Array` which cannot be converted to and stored (in any meaningful way) as a an 8-bit integer.

Solution: Either make `arr` a generic `Array` whose elements can be arrays or - probably the more advanced but usually more performant solution - store your multidimensional array as a single flat array of size `numrows * numcols` and access an element via `arr[column + row * numcols]`:

```js
var numrows = 5, numcols = 4;
var arr = new Int8Array(numrows * numcols).fill(0);

arr[3 + 1 * numrows] = 1; // col = 3, row = 1

console.log (arr);
```

Comment: Can I interpret this **read** operation multiply numcols with row (i.e `arr[column + row * numcols]`) while **write** operation multiply numrows with row (i.e `arr[column + row * numrows]`)? This seems wrong to me since read/write formula are inconsistent.